# Core Text - Get Pixel Coordinates from NSRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-text

How would I get a `CGRect` from an `NSRange` for text rendered with Core Text?

I am using Core Text with an `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an absolute pain but can be done.

You need to get all of the lines in the frame using `CTFrameGetLines()`, check if their character range is in the range you're looking for using `CTLineGetStringRange()`, use `CTLineGetTypographicBounds()` to find how big the line itself would render as, and use `CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex()` to determine the actual position of the start/end character of the range (if the line is just a subrange of the desired range).

Combining all of this and adding up offsets and heights and such can get you what you want. Note that `CTLineGetImageBounds()` doesn't work without a graphics context (and, from what I gather, it is pretty expensive anyway) and is not necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: A detailed answer, thanks very much! It's always a pain to find all the functions that are required for things such as this. :)

Comment: @Joshua can u share ur code when implementing this answer?? i think i have the some problem and can not solved it until 3 weeks, help me, please...

Comment: @Risma I never actually got round to implementing this but everything you need is in Sean's answer.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem at the moment, and I'm hung up at a certain point - I can't seem to get "string access" to the CTLineRef for the text. Any ideas? Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/bryanjclark/7036101

Comment: @bryanjclark did you ever find a solution to this, I'm struggling with similar issues

Answer (score 2):

FIrst determine the line(s) in which the range you are interested in lies is. Then call `CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex()` to get an offset of a specific string position from the start of the line. Together with `CTLineGetImageBounds()`, it should be possible to calculate a `CGPoint` position of the first and last characters in your range.