# How to allow text highlighting in an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, highlighting, core-text

I'm making an iPad magazine app where the user will be able to highlight any amount of the text. These highlights will need to be saved and appear everytime that article is loaded.

Can I do this somehow with CoreText (which is currently what I am using to allow multi-columned formatting)?

I have noticed that selecting text using HTML in a UIWebView doesn't work properly if there are images within the text.

Anyone have any advice?

Thanks a lot,

-Chris

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779051/how-to-highlight-coretext-with-changing-highlight-colors

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in support in CoreText for selection or "Copy & Paste", but you can make your own selection engine using some CoreText functions.

Take a look at this other topic post.

[Core Text - select text in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979592/is-it-possible-to-select-the-text-rendered-by-core-text-in-iphone/11005546#11005546)